# Issue with Git Push and Jenkins Build

Tags: git, jenkins

Am new to using "git". The issue is this. I committed some files using 'git commit' and then pushed the code using 'git push'. The build failed in Jenkins due to some issues. So I abandoned the changes. Thenafter, I corrected the previous issue in my local. Did a second commit. This time it just showed the one file i had changed. When doing 'git status' it said, i was ahead of the head by 2 commits. So I just pushed the code. And this time the build was all fine but Jenkins says something as follows

```
              Build Failed
              http://1xxx/23/ : SUCCESS
              http:yyy/7/ : FAILURE
```

The failure link points to the failure with the first push. What should be done now? I just want the latest changes i pushed to be merged with the head. Am i in big trouble here?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

> git pull --rebase

--rebase option means that git will move your local commit aside, synchronise with the remote and then try to apply your commits from the new state